# Настройка webpack и модули

Tags: webpack

Подскажите, пожалуйста, попытался настроить вебпак и все вроде работает, за исключением той вещи что я не могу накинуть стили на #root, я поставил уникальные имена для изоляйции стилей, дабы модулями пользоваться, если их убрать на рут навешиваются стили, можно конечно заколхозить, но не хочется, подскажите где накосячил

```
  const cssLoaderWithModules = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: {
        localIdentName: isDev ? '[path][name]__[local]' : '[hash:base64:8]', //если поставить просто [local] то все работает
      },
    },
  }
```

приложение в root монтируется, но стили не навешиваются

```
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```